# How can I change the background color of this block using BootStrap framework?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am very new in **BootStrap** development and I have the following theme implemented using it: http://lnx.asper-eritrea.com/

As you can see in the content area there are 3 boxes (respectively named **La Situazione**, **Archivio** and **Archivio Video**).

This is the related code:

```
<section id="lancio-progetti">
    <div class="row">

        <a href="#">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="box-progetto">
                <h3 class="text-center">La Situazione</h3>
                <!--<p class="text-center"><img src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/AsperTheme/assets/img/pencil-3.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive"></p>-->
                <p class="text-center"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/icona-situazione-big.gif" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
                </p>
                <p>
                    La situazione in sintesi: situazione politica dell'Eritrea           
                </p>
                <!--<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block upper-botton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> Visita Archivio Attività</a>-->
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
        </a>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="box-progetto">
                <h3 class="text-center">Archivio</h3>
                <!--<p class="text-center"><img src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/AsperTheme/assets/img/pencil-1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive"></p>-->
                <p class="text-center"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/icona-comunicati-big.gif" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
                </p>
                <p>
                    Archivio storico che raccoglie i nostri comunicati e le notizie pubblicate
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block upper-botton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> Visita Archivio Comunicati</a>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="box-progetto">
                <h3 class="text-center">Archivio Video</h3>
                <!--<p class="text-center"><img src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/AsperTheme/assets/img/pencil-2.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive"></p>-->
                <p class="text-center"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/icona-video.gif" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
                </p>
                <p>
                    Raccolta di videodocumenti e testimonianze video
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block upper-botton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> Visita Archivio Video</a>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->

    </div><!-- /.row -->
</section><!-- /section lancio progetti-->
```

As you can see the first box is different from the others 2 boxes because I have moove the link on the entire block and not only on the:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block upper-botton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> Visita Archivio Video</a>
```

My problem is: using BootStrap can I obtain the same effect (the background color change when I put the mouse cursor on the link) that I have on the buttons links on the other 2 blocks?

Tnx

Comment: So you want the entire first block to change background color on hover?

Comment: Like this? http://note.io/1sOg3zI

Comment: Oh dear, it looks like Bootstrap is becoming the "Use jQuery" of the CSS world

Comment: @Skram no, the entire square block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CSS, change this:

```
.upper-botton:hover, .upper-botton:focus, .upper-botton:active, .upper-botton.active, .open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
   color: #ffffff;
   background-color: #F1B000;
   border-color: #285e8e;
}
```

to this (notice the addition of `.box-progetto:hover` to the CSS rule):

```
.upper-botton:hover, .upper-botton:focus, .upper-botton:active, .upper-botton.active, .open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary, .box-progetto:hover {
   color: #ffffff;
   background-color: #F1B000;
   border-color: #285e8e;
}
```